# How to combine the n arguments in c() [R]?

Tags: r, matrix, vector

I have generate a random matrix d, then make some matrix operation.
Finally, I need to store the result in vector B. Code is below

```
set.seed(42)
n <- 3
m <- 4
d <- matrix(sample(0:255, n*m, replace=T), nrow = n, ncol = m)
# some matrix operation
B <-c(d[1,], d[2,], d[3,])
> d
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]  234  212  188  180
[2,]  239  164   34  117
[3,]   73  132  168  184
> B
 [1] 234 212 188 180 239 164  34 117  73 132 168 184
>
```

Could some one please explain me how to rewrite last 
line via a function in order to combine the n arguments in one vector?

I have tried

```
B <- sapply(1:n, FUN=function(i) B<-c(d[i,]))
```

Thank!

Comment: `c(d)` will return a vector with the elements of the matrix `d`.

Comment: @eipi10 By column, though, right? If they want it by row maybe transpose first?

Comment: Yes, scanned the question too quickly. `c(t(d))` to transpose first and therefore output by row instead of by column.

Comment: @eipi10, thanks for very short solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function should do it (overkill, since `c(t(d))` as suggested by @joran works fine):

```
vectorizeByRow <- function(IN) {
    OUT <- rep(NA_real_, length(IN))
    nc <- ncol(IN)
    nr <- nrow(IN)
    a <- seq(1, length(IN), nc)
    b <- a + nc - 1
    for (n in 1:length(a)) {
        OUT[a[n]:b[n]] <- IN[n,]
        }
    OUT
    }
```

Use:

```
vectorizeByRow(d)
```

Produces:

```
 [1] 234 212 188 180 239 164  34 117  73 132
[11] 168 184
```

This is from the `HandyStuff` [package](https://github.com/bryanhanson/HandyStuff).  Disclaimer: I am the author.